# Get variable value from for loop in batch file

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, variables, disk, wmic

I am trying to list inline partitions separated by plus sign. Code below make that for me, but at the end of course is the last one plus. It's any possibility to remove it (last plus) and save it to variable that I can use later in script?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get name /format:value') do @echo | set /p drives=%%d+
```

Comment: `set "drives=%drives:0,-1%"` removes the last character.

Comment: I'd build the string in advance rather than displaying each sub-string in the loop, then you can easily split off the last character. If you want to do it in the loop directly, you'll have to make sure that there are no superfluous `+`-signs added, or you have to overwrite the last one with a space…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest idea is to use a variable, ensure it is not defined before you begin, then only prefix each drive letter with the `+` character, if that variable is already defined.

Example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "DriveList="
For /F Tokens^=2^ Delims^=^" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 LogicalDisk Assoc /ResultRole:DeviceID 2^>NUL') Do If Defined DriveList (
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For %%H In ("!DriveList!") Do EndLocal ^
    & Set "DriveList=%%~H+%%G") Else Set "DriveList=%%G"
Echo(%DriveList%
Pause
```

*It looks as if you may wish to use `Set /P` instead of `Echo(`, although why you would want a string like `C:+D:+E:+G:` is another matter!*

Comment: It works perfect! Syntax was to difficult for me. Thank you a lot for your help.